# Yii2 - Set safe attributes on scenarios

Tags: yii, yii2, attributes, scenarios

How can I safe my attributes for a massive assignment when I'm using a scenario (in my example 'update' scenario)?

Here is my rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_id', 'type', 'name', 'status'], 'required'],
        [['country_id', 'address', 'name', 'status'], 'safe', 'on' => 'update'],
    ];
}

public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios['update'] = ['user_id', 'type', 'name'];
    return $scenarios;
}
```

When I'm checking the safe attributes in my controller using $model->safeAttributes(), I'm only getting the required attributes that are in the required of the 'update' scenario of the function scenarios().

And of course, the $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) function does not retreive other attributes.

How can I put them safe?
Even if I want to add some other rules, I can't find the way!

Comment: are you setting the scenario before you call the `$model->safeAttributes()`

Comment: Yes,  I'm defining the scenario just after the findModel function like this:
`public function actionUpdate($id)`
`{`
`$model = $this->findModel($id);`
`$model->scenario = 'CU';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add them all in scenario

```
$scenarios['update'] = ['user_id', 'type', 'name', 'country_id', 'address', 'name', 'status'];
```

Comment: If I'm going to do this, it means that all these fields become required. But I don't want that.

Comment: @SamirIZZA No, it means that all these fields are safe and can be massively assigned. Required fields you configure in rules.

Comment: Oh man, you're right! I don't know how I understood it that way. I always thought that this way we declare the required fields and not the active fields. But I was wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SamirIZZA I’m happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the scenario before you load the model:

```
$model->setScenario('update');
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
```